# Matplotlib animation.FuncAnimation() animation miss first frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, animation, matplotlib-animation

I am new to both Python and Matplotlib. I'have this code to plot a trajectory in a 3d Matplotlib subplot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

from itertools import islice

import sympy as sym
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

from sympy import Eq, solve




class FunZ:
    
    def __init__(self, f):  
  
        self.x, self.y  = sym.symbols('x y')
        
        self.f = parse_expr(f)
        
        # print('f : ', self.f)
        
    def evalu(self, xx, yy):
    
        return float(self.f.subs({self.x: xx, self.y: yy}).evalf())
    

    def derX(self, xx, yy):        
        
        self.dx = sym.diff(self.f, self.x)
        
        # print('dx : ', self.dx)
        
        return float(self.dx.subs({self.x: xx, self.y: yy}).evalf())
    
    def derY(self, xx, yy):
        
        self.dy = sym.diff(self.f, self.y)
        
        # print('dy :', self.dy)
        
        return float(self.dy.subs({self.x: xx, self.y: yy}).evalf())
    
    def derXY(self, xx, yy):
        
        return [float(self.derX(xx, yy)), float(self.derY(xx, yy))]
    
    def minim(self):
        
        self.dx = sym.diff(self.f, self.x)
        self.dy = sym.diff(self.f, self.y)
        print('dx : ', self.dx)
        print('dy : ', self.dy)
        
        eq1 = Eq(self.dx ,0)
        
        eq2 = Eq(self.dy ,0)
        
        solu = solve((eq1,eq2), (self.x, self.y), dict= False)
        
        print(solu, type(solu))
        
        return solu

XX = np.linspace(-4, 4, 100)

YY = np.linspace(-4, 4, 100)

funz = FunZ('x**2 + y**2 + 2*y + 2')

ij = [(x, y, funz.evalu(x, y)) for x in XX for y in YY]


arr = np.array(ij, dtype=float)

# print(arr, arr.size, arr.shape, arr.dtype)


der_x = [(a, b, funz.derX(a, b)) for a in XX for b in YY] 

derX = np.array(der_x)

# print(derX, derX.size, derX.shape, derX.dtype)


der_y = [(a, b, funz.derY(a, b)) for a in XX for b in YY] 

derY = np.array(der_y)

# print(derY, derY.size, derY.shape, derY.dtype)


x = arr[:, 0]
y = arr[:, 1]

data = arr[:, 2]




fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim([-4,4])
ax.set_ylim([-4,4])
ax.set_zlim([-3,50])
ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, data, color="red", alpha=0.5)


### devo duplicare primo elemento della lista altrimenti skippa a visualizzare i primi due sul video

# trajectory =  [(2.5, 3.5, 27.5),(2.5, 3.5, 27.5), (2.0, 3.0, 21.0), (1.5, 2.5, 15.5), (1.0, 2.0, 11.0), (0.5, 1.5, 7.5), (0.0, 1.0, 5.0), (0.0, 0.5, 3.25), (0.0, 0.0, 2.0), (0.0, -0.5, 1.25), (0.0, -1.0, 1.0)]

trajectory =  [(2.5, 3.5, 27.5), (2.0, 3.0, 21.0), (1.5, 2.5, 15.5), (1.0, 2.0, 11.0), (0.5, 1.5, 7.5), (0.0, 1.0, 5.0), (0.0, 0.5, 3.25), (0.0, 0.0, 2.0), (0.0, -0.5, 1.25), (0.0, -1.0, 1.0)]

print('len trajectory : ', len(trajectory))


i = islice(trajectory, 0 , len(trajectory), 1)


pippo = None
def animate(j):  #funziona senza stop iteration with animation.save
    
    global pippo
    
    try: 
        coord = next(i)
        
    except:
        print('coord empty')
        return
    
    if pippo:
        pippo.remove()
    
    print(coord)
                
    x = coord[0]
    y = coord[1]
    z = coord[2]
      
    pippo = ax.scatter(x,y,z)          
    
    return pippo

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000, frames=len(trajectory), repeat=False)  # e' necessario



plt.show()
plt.close('all')


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim([-4,4])
ax.set_ylim([-4,4])
ax.set_zlim([-3,50])
ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, data, color="red", alpha=0.5)


print('#####################')

i = islice(trajectory, 0 , len(trajectory), 1)

ani2 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000, frames=len(trajectory), repeat=False)

# writervideo = animation.FFMpegWriter(fps=1, codec="h264") 
# ani2.save('video_steeper.mp4', writer=writervideo)

ani2.save("movie.gif", writer=animation.PillowWriter(fps=1))
```

I am struggling trying to understand why to have a proper animation and saved animation I need to duplicate the first element of my `trajectory` list ((2.5, 3.5, 27.5)).

If I don't do so the animation and my gif show only 9 points instead of 10, see resulting output:

movie from 10 element list `trajectory` :

[image]

movie from 11 element list `trajectory` (first one duplicated):

[image]

I've tried a lot to figure out what is going on but can't understand, it is strange that my `print` statement inside `animate` function prints exactly 11 and 10 points for the two different list but both of them miss a frame in the animation and file. Any clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that your issue comes from the iterable `i` you are creating and the use of the function `next`. I am not exactly sure why it's happening but if instead of creating your iterable `i` you just index your trajectory directly then your animation works as expected.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from itertools import islice
import sympy as sym
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
from sympy import Eq, solve

class FunZ:    
    def __init__(self, f):  
        self.x, self.y  = sym.symbols('x y')
        self.f = parse_expr(f)
        
    def evalu(self, xx, yy):   
        return float(self.f.subs({self.x: xx, self.y: yy}).evalf())
  
    def derX(self, xx, yy):        
        self.dx = sym.diff(self.f, self.x)
        return float(self.dx.subs({self.x: xx, self.y: yy}).evalf())
    
    def derY(self, xx, yy):
        self.dy = sym.diff(self.f, self.y)
        return float(self.dy.subs({self.x: xx, self.y: yy}).evalf())
    
    def derXY(self, xx, yy):
        return [float(self.derX(xx, yy)), float(self.derY(xx, yy))]
    
    def minim(self):     
        self.dx = sym.diff(self.f, self.x)
        self.dy = sym.diff(self.f, self.y)
        print('dx : ', self.dx)
        print('dy : ', self.dy)      
        eq1 = Eq(self.dx ,0)   
        eq2 = Eq(self.dy ,0)
        solu = solve((eq1,eq2), (self.x, self.y), dict= False)
        print(solu, type(solu))
        return solu

XX = np.linspace(-4, 4, 100)
YY = np.linspace(-4, 4, 100)

funz = FunZ('x**2 + y**2 + 2*y + 2')
ij = [(x, y, funz.evalu(x, y)) for x in XX for y in YY]
arr = np.array(ij, dtype=float)

der_x = [(a, b, funz.derX(a, b)) for a in XX for b in YY] 
derX = np.array(der_x)
der_y = [(a, b, funz.derY(a, b)) for a in XX for b in YY] 
derY = np.array(der_y)

x = arr[:, 0]
y = arr[:, 1]
data = arr[:, 2]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim([-4,4])
ax.set_ylim([-4,4])
ax.set_zlim([-3,50])
ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, data, color="red", alpha=0.5)

trajectory =  [(2.5, 3.5, 27.5), (2.0, 3.0, 21.0), (1.5, 2.5, 15.5), (1.0, 2.0, 11.0), (0.5, 1.5, 7.5), (0.0, 1.0, 5.0), (0.0, 0.5, 3.25), (0.0, 0.0, 2.0), (0.0, -0.5, 1.25), (0.0, -1.0, 1.0)]
print('len trajectory : ', len(trajectory))

pippo = None
def animate(j):  # it works without stop iteration with animation.save
    
    global pippo

    x = trajectory[j][0]
    y = trajectory[j][1]
    z = trajectory[j][2]

    if pippo is not None:
        pippo.remove()
    pippo = ax.scatter(x,y,z)          
    return pippo

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000, frames=len(trajectory), repeat=False)  # it is required
plt.show()
```

The output gives:

[image]

Comment: Could be but print(coord) comes from the iterator too and it actually prints all the 10 or 11 points

Comment: I suspect that your iterator `i` being declared in the global scope is messing things up in your animation.

Comment: Maybe it related to: ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 128),
                    init_func=init, blit=True) —-> init_funct=init see example : https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/animation_api.html

Comment: I’ ll try to pass the iterator to animate(). Do you know what I stands for ? If I remember right my code throw an error if missing

Comment: It’s frames=len(trajectory) necessary in your example ??

Comment: Well, you do need to pass the number of frames to your `FunAnimation` function so yep it's necessary

Comment: not really, but got the point, thanks for your time indeed, I should start to try read documentation (jargon is still big steep wall to me, instead of looking for tutorials

Comment: hi got it if you add print('animate__', str(j), '_______________________________________', pippo) before global pippo in def animate, you 'll see that animate is actually called 11 times twice at the beginning with index j=0, so thats why my own iterator was screwed up. If you add init_func=init_animate in ani, you'll see that aniomate its called only 10 times

Comment: Good catch! Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Well fiddled a little bit with `FuncAnimation` adding an `init_func` :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

from itertools import islice

import sympy as sym
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

from sympy import Eq, solve




class FunZ:
    
    def __init__(self, f):  
  
        self.x, self.y  = sym.symbols('x y')
        
        self.f = parse_expr(f)
        
        # print('f : ', self.f)
        
    def evalu(self, xx, yy):
    
        return float(self.f.subs({self.x: xx, self.y: yy}).evalf())
    

    def derX(self, xx, yy):        
        
        self.dx = sym.diff(self.f, self.x)
        
        # print('dx : ', self.dx)
        
        return float(self.dx.subs({self.x: xx, self.y: yy}).evalf())
    
    def derY(self, xx, yy):
        
        self.dy = sym.diff(self.f, self.y)
        
        # print('dy :', self.dy)
        
        return float(self.dy.subs({self.x: xx, self.y: yy}).evalf())
    
    def derXY(self, xx, yy):
        
        return [float(self.derX(xx, yy)), float(self.derY(xx, yy))]
    
    def minim(self):
        
        self.dx = sym.diff(self.f, self.x)
        self.dy = sym.diff(self.f, self.y)
        print('dx : ', self.dx)
        print('dy : ', self.dy)
        
        eq1 = Eq(self.dx ,0)
        
        eq2 = Eq(self.dy ,0)
        
        solu = solve((eq1,eq2), (self.x, self.y), dict= False)
        
        print(solu, type(solu))
        
        return solu

XX = np.linspace(-4, 4, 100)

YY = np.linspace(-4, 4, 100)

funz = FunZ('x**2 + y**2 + 2*y + 2')

ij = [(x, y, funz.evalu(x, y)) for x in XX for y in YY]


arr = np.array(ij, dtype=float)

# print(arr, arr.size, arr.shape, arr.dtype)


der_x = [(a, b, funz.derX(a, b)) for a in XX for b in YY] 

derX = np.array(der_x)

# print(derX, derX.size, derX.shape, derX.dtype)


der_y = [(a, b, funz.derY(a, b)) for a in XX for b in YY] 

derY = np.array(der_y)

# print(derY, derY.size, derY.shape, derY.dtype)


x = arr[:, 0]
y = arr[:, 1]

data = arr[:, 2]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim([-4,4])
ax.set_ylim([-4,4])
ax.set_zlim([-3,50])
ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, data, color="red", alpha=0.5)

trajectory =  [(2.5, 3.5, 27.5), (2.0, 3.0, 21.0), (1.5, 2.5, 15.5), (1.0, 2.0, 11.0), (0.5, 1.5, 7.5), (0.0, 1.0, 5.0), (0.0, 0.5, 3.25), (0.0, 0.0, 2.0), (0.0, -0.5, 1.25), (0.0, -1.0, 1.0)]

print('len trajectory : ', len(trajectory))
i = islice(trajectory, 0 , len(trajectory), 1)

def init_animate():
    ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, data, color="green", alpha=0.5)
    
pippo = None
def animate(j):  #funziona senza stop iteration with animation.save
    
    global pippo
    
    try: 
        coord = next(i)
        
    except:
        print('coord empty')
        return
    
    if pippo:
        pippo.remove()
    
    print(coord)
                
    x = coord[0]
    y = coord[1]
    z = coord[2]
      
    pippo = ax.scatter(x,y,z)          
    
    return pippo

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000, frames=len(trajectory),init_func=init_animate, repeat=False)  

plt.show()
plt.close('all')

print('#####################')
```

was able to get all the 10 points moving on gif:

[image]

was able to remove the `frames` arg too but just for the visualization not the saving of my animation, see:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

from itertools import islice

import sympy as sym
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

from sympy import Eq, solve




class FunZ:
    
    def __init__(self, f):  
  
        self.x, self.y  = sym.symbols('x y')
        
        self.f = parse_expr(f)
        
        # print('f : ', self.f)
        
    def evalu(self, xx, yy):
    
        return float(self.f.subs({self.x: xx, self.y: yy}).evalf())
    

    def derX(self, xx, yy):        
        
        self.dx = sym.diff(self.f, self.x)
        
        # print('dx : ', self.dx)
        
        return float(self.dx.subs({self.x: xx, self.y: yy}).evalf())
    
    def derY(self, xx, yy):
        
        self.dy = sym.diff(self.f, self.y)
        
        # print('dy :', self.dy)
        
        return float(self.dy.subs({self.x: xx, self.y: yy}).evalf())
    
    def derXY(self, xx, yy):
        
        return [float(self.derX(xx, yy)), float(self.derY(xx, yy))]
    
    def minim(self):
        
        self.dx = sym.diff(self.f, self.x)
        self.dy = sym.diff(self.f, self.y)
        print('dx : ', self.dx)
        print('dy : ', self.dy)
        
        eq1 = Eq(self.dx ,0)
        
        eq2 = Eq(self.dy ,0)
        
        solu = solve((eq1,eq2), (self.x, self.y), dict= False)
        
        print(solu, type(solu))
        
        return solu

XX = np.linspace(-4, 4, 100)

YY = np.linspace(-4, 4, 100)

funz = FunZ('x**2 + y**2 + 2*y + 2')

ij = [(x, y, funz.evalu(x, y)) for x in XX for y in YY]


arr = np.array(ij, dtype=float)

# print(arr, arr.size, arr.shape, arr.dtype)


der_x = [(a, b, funz.derX(a, b)) for a in XX for b in YY] 

derX = np.array(der_x)

# print(derX, derX.size, derX.shape, derX.dtype)


der_y = [(a, b, funz.derY(a, b)) for a in XX for b in YY] 

derY = np.array(der_y)

# print(derY, derY.size, derY.shape, derY.dtype)


x = arr[:, 0]
y = arr[:, 1]

data = arr[:, 2]




fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim([-4,4])
ax.set_ylim([-4,4])
ax.set_zlim([-3,50])
ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, data, color="red", alpha=0.5)


### devo duplicare primo elemento della lista altrimenti skippa a visualizzare i primi due sul video

trajectory =  [(2.5, 3.5, 27.5), (2.0, 3.0, 21.0), (1.5, 2.5, 15.5), (1.0, 2.0, 11.0), (0.5, 1.5, 7.5), (0.0, 1.0, 5.0), (0.0, 0.5, 3.25), (0.0, 0.0, 2.0), (0.0, -0.5, 1.25), (0.0, -1.0, 1.0)]

# trajectory =  [(2.5, 3.5, 27.5), (2.0, 3.0, 21.0), (1.5, 2.5, 15.5), (1.0, 2.0, 11.0), (0.5, 1.5, 7.5), (0.0, 1.0, 5.0), (0.0, 0.5, 3.25), (0.0, 0.0, 2.0), (0.0, -0.5, 1.25), (0.0, -1.0, 1.0)]

print('len trajectory : ', len(trajectory))


i = islice(trajectory, 0 , len(trajectory), 1)





def init_animate():
    ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, data, color="blue", alpha=0.5)
    
pippo = None
def animate(j):  #funziona senza stop iteration with animation.save

    global pippo

    try: 
        
        coord = next(i)
        print(coord)
        
    except:
        print('coord empty')
        global ani
        global ani2
        ani = None
        ani2 = None
        return 
    
    if pippo:
        pippo.remove()
    
    # print(coord)
                
    x = coord[0]
    y = coord[1]
    z = coord[2]
      
    pippo = ax.scatter(x,y,z)          
    
    return pippo


# ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate ,frames=len(trajectory),init_func=init_animate, interval=1000, repeat=False) 
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init_animate, interval=1000, repeat=False) 

plt.show()

print('test to see if everything is fine')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim([-4,4])
ax.set_ylim([-4,4])
ax.set_zlim([-3,50])
ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, data, color="red", alpha=0.5)


print('#####################')

i = islice(trajectory, 0 , len(trajectory), 1)

ani2 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init_animate, interval=1000, repeat=False).save("movie_init_no-frames.gif", writer=animation.PillowWriter(fps=1))
```

dont know what is going on but alghoritm keeps running, output:

```
len trajectory :  10
(2.5, 3.5, 27.5)
(2.0, 3.0, 21.0)
(1.5, 2.5, 15.5)
(1.0, 2.0, 11.0)
(0.5, 1.5, 7.5)
(0.0, 1.0, 5.0)
(0.0, 0.5, 3.25)
(0.0, 0.0, 2.0)
(0.0, -0.5, 1.25)
(0.0, -1.0, 1.0)
coord empty
test to see if everything is fine
#####################
(2.5, 3.5, 27.5)
(2.0, 3.0, 21.0)
(1.5, 2.5, 15.5)
(1.0, 2.0, 11.0)
(0.5, 1.5, 7.5)
(0.0, 1.0, 5.0)
(0.0, 0.5, 3.25)
(0.0, 0.0, 2.0)
(0.0, -0.5, 1.25)
(0.0, -1.0, 1.0)
coord empty
coord empty
coord empty
^Z
[9]+  Stopped
```

I suppose it relates to the inners of  `FuncAnimation`.
Nevertheless I should have took the time to try to understant `j` Documentation
as per  `help(matplotlib.animation)`

......

```
class FuncAnimation(TimedAnimation)
     |  FuncAnimation(fig, func, frames=None, init_func=None, fargs=None, save_count=None, *, cache_frame_data=True, **kwargs)
     |  
     |  Makes an animation by repeatedly calling a function *func*.
     |  
     |  Parameters
     |  ----------
     |  fig : `~matplotlib.figure.Figure`
     |      The figure object used to get needed events, such as draw or resize.
     |  
     |  func : callable
     |      The function to call at each frame.  The first argument will
     |      be the next value in *frames*.   Any additional positional
     |      arguments can be supplied via the *fargs* parameter.
     |  
     |      The required signature is::
     |  
     |          def func(frame, *fargs) -> iterable_of_artists
     |  
     |      If ``blit == True``, *func* must return an iterable of all artists
     |      that were modified or created. This information is used by the blitting
     |      algorithm to determine which parts of the figure have to be updated.
     |      The return value is unused if ``blit == False`` and may be omitted in
     |      that case.
```

......